# How to print body of response on urllib2.URLError?

Tags: python, rest, http

In a script I am creating I am posting a lot of data to a REST API.

The script is quite modularized and at the top level somewhere I am catching a URLError. I need to know what is in the body of the response, because there will be an error message in there.

Is there a method on URLError that I can use?

```
    try:
        (calling some function that throws URLError)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "Error: " + str(e.body_or_something)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. You have an access to the response via `e.readlines()`:

```
    try:
        (calling some function that throws URLError)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print e.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documenet: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError

> **exception urllib2.URLError** The handlers raise this exception (or
>   derived exceptions) when they run into a problem. It is a subclass of
>   IOError.
>
> *reason* The reason for this error. It can be a message string or
>   another exception instance (socket.error for remote URLs, OSError for
>   local URLs).
>
> **exception urllib2.HTTPError** Though being an exception (a subclass of
>   URLError), an HTTPError can also function as a non-exceptional
>   file-like return value (the same thing that urlopen() returns). This
>   is useful when handling exotic HTTP errors, such as requests for
>   authentication.
>
> *code* An HTTP status code as defined in RFC 2616. This numeric value
>   corresponds to a value found in the dictionary of codes as found in
>   BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.responses.
>
> *reason* The reason for this error. It can be a message string or
>   another exception instance.

So you can access the response body when the request raise **urllib2.HTTPError**.

Try this:

```
try:
    (calling some function that throws URLError)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    body = e.readlines()
    print e.code, e.reason, body
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print e.reason
except:
    sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
```